# Understand working of host file

Tags: .net, windows, host

Hi i understand how host file works in particular

e.g. in my project if i write name of my server in connection string e.g.

```
  faisal:1468;user=abc;password=cde
```

and in host file i do like below

```
  faisal 192.1.1.1
```

the project will automatically map to the ip in host file

But lets say in my connection string i have following

```
  faisal.mydomain.com:1468;user=abc;password=def
```

Do i need to but entry in host file against above server name as well or it is self sufficient in itself . One other thing how windows actually knows that it has to look in host file against a name written in project which can be java or .net

Comment: @ppeterka you should write this as an answer so the OP can accept it.

Comment: @booyaa Thanks, I was in the process of doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how windows actually knows that it has to look in host file

The operation system (not only Windows) always checks `hosts` first, then continues with the DNS lookup.

Conclusion: You should add `faisal.mydomain.com` to the hosts file too, unless your DNS has that registered...

Recommended reading: [Domain Name System (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System)

> in my host file there is no entry for this machine we just use faisal.abcworld.com and it connects to the machine faisal which is also on abcworld.com domain

This means that:

1. `faisal.abcworld.com` is checked in the hosts file -- not found
2. the DNS is asked about it
3. DNS finds the faisal.abcworld.com domain registered (it's actually more complicated than this, this might have several steps until finally found. Read the article on the Wiki. It is well worth, if you want to continue working in a networked environment...)
4. it resolves the server
5. the server parses your request, and responds appropriately

Comment: in my host file there is no entry for this machine we just use faisal.abcworld.com and it connects to the machine faisal which is also on abcworld.com domain . Is it because both machines are on same domain ?

Comment: You should read the wiki article that ppeterka linked. It should make things clearer.

Answer (score 1):

The IP address comes first in a Hosts file, so your example should be

```
192.1.1.1 faisal
```

The host name has to match exactly. So if you have a mapping for `faisal` then that will *only* match for the hostname `faisal`. It won't match `test.faisal` or `faisal.com`.

In your example, you would need to add an entry for `faisal.mydomain.com` to your hosts file.

Comment: in my host file there is no entry for this machine we just use faisal.abcworld.com and it connects to the machine faisal which is also on abcworld.com domain . Is it because both machines are on same domain ?